# How to convert Hex to uint32_t in nodejs

Tags: node.js, hex

I have hex: 6e128300
in c++ uint32_t = 500

But I dont know how to convert this hex to int in nodejs.

Comment: `6e128300` is 1846706944 in decimal, not even close to 500. 500 is 0x1F4

Comment: Ok, so how to make strtol in nodejs

Answer (score -1):

`parseInt(myHexString, 16)` should do it.  Node.js is just JavaScript so the the builtin number parsing functions are available.